# stale element reference element is not attached to the page document , selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing stale element reference element is not attached to the page document issue while executing the below test.
with

```
driver.findElementById("inputId").sendKeys("45873");
```

i am able to locate the elements and sending values too but I am getting the above issue too.

---

```
for (WebElement item: productivityButtons) {
 String appName = item.getAttribute("appName");
 if (item.getAttribute("appName").equals("ReceiveApp")) {
  item.click();
  String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
  for (String handle: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
   if (!handle.equals(currentWindow))
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
  }
   driver.findElementById("inputId").sendKeys("45873");

 } 
}
```

Comment: Can you mention for which element you are getting this exception? Also, it would be helpful if you can include the html snippet for the said element.

Comment: driver.findElementById("inputId").sendKeys("45873");
<ion-view view-title="app" hide-back-button="true"> <div class="bar bar-header pallet-search"> <div class="list list-inset search-box" ng-show="receive.scanMode"> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="inputId" ng-model="nmbr" on-enter="receive.scanItem()" > <div class="ion-search custom-search-button" ng-click="SearchMode()"></div> <div class="ion-mic-a custom-search-button end-border"></div> </div> </div> </ion-view>

Comment: StaleElement exception is observed if the element you are trying to locate it detached from the DOM. Simply, adding a retry  will resolve the issue. But there is no exact fix for this. Refer this [Link](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html) . You might get some idea.

Comment: You need to break the loop after sendKeys..